# Graalvm windows native-image without console

Tags: windows, graalvm

I have created native image from a simple application using graalvm on Windows 10.
It's working very well, but the application is opening a console.

Is it possible to create a non-console application with graalvm ?

Comment: I don't see an option, Unix utilities tend to drop the ball on these Windows-specific executable file options.  If you have the Microsoft toolset available then you can use [Editbin.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem) to change the file header's subsystem target from CONSOLE to WINDOWS.

Comment: thanks, it worked. This could be an actual answer :
editbin /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS my.exe

Comment: Don't forget to post it and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the time being (09-17-2019), there is no option available in graalvm to create a non-console application.
The workarround is to edit the binary with [Editbin.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem) available in the Windows SDK :

```
> editbin /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS my.exe
```